# 2d animation keyframes not showing up

Tags: animation, keyframes, 2d

The keyframes for 2d animation is not showing up, even when im in object mode no keyframes are showing up. And they are no youtube videos that show this problem. Anybuddy know what to do`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I'm good a pushing buttons.
[image]

Comment: Can u explain what that button is and what happens when u switch it off ?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying my question:) seems like it's turning the keyframes on and off. Im still a animation noob so i dont know alot about blender yet.

Comment: I'm probably more of a noob than you. I can't explain anything in Blender!   At the moment I'm trying to change fill colors during a 2D animation. no luck so far.    
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPN5ASYFkbE